# Quickbooks- "Query" API Call with CreateDate

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I want to retrieve vendors from Quickbooks Which have been created before a specific date. The API has provided the method "query" to retrieve date using a SQL statement.

How can i use the "CreateTime" in the where clause to filter date by a specific data.

Regards,
Sarindu.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Vendor WHERE MetaData.CreateTime >= '2009-10-14T04:05:05-07:00' AND MetaData.CreateTime <= '2012-10-14T04:05:05-07:00'
```

Of course, it must be encoded in the request e.g.

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1234/query?query=SELECT%20FROM%20Customer%20WHERE%20Metadata.LastUpdatedTime%20%3E+%272011-08-10T10%3A20%3A30-0700%27
```

Docs: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations